# Execute a CMake function on every build-time

Tags: cmake

I have two cmake function to check resources/shader files are not found/ modified matching to build.

Check.cmake

```
function(Check sourcefile destinationfile)
    if(NOT EXISTS ${destinationfile})
        execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
                -E copy ${sourcefile} ${destinationfile})
    elseif(${sourcefile} IS_NEWER_THAN ${destinationfile})
        execute_process(COMMAND ${MSGMERGE_EXECUTABLE}
                "--update" ${destinationfile} ${sourcefile}
                OUTPUT_QUIET ERROR_VARIABLE error RESULT_VARIABLE ret)

        if(ret) # Have to do this hack as msgmerge prints to stderr.
            message(SEND_ERROR "${error}")
        endif()
    endif()
endfunction()
```

AddResources.cmake

```
include(./Check.cmake)

function(AddResources project)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE resources ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/project1/Resources/*)
    file(GLOB_RECURSE shaders ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/project1/Shaders/*)
    foreach( each_file1 ${resources} )
        get_filename_component(targetFile ${each_file1} NAME)
        if(WIN32)
          set(destinationfile "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Release/${targetFile}")
          set(destinationfile2 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Debug/${targetFile}")
          set(sourcefile ${each_file1})
          Check(${sourcefile} ${destinationfile})
          Check(${sourcefile} ${destinationfile2})
        else ()
          set(destinationfile "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${targetFile}")
          set(sourcefile ${each_file1})
          Check(${sourcefile} ${destinationfile})
        endif()
    endforeach(each_file1)
    foreach( each_file2 ${shaders} )
        get_filename_component(targetFile ${each_file2} NAME)
        if(WIN32)
          set(destinationfile "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Release/${targetFile}")
          set(destinationfile2 "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Debug/${targetFile}")
          set(sourcefile ${each_file2})
          Check(${sourcefile} ${destinationfile})
          Check(${sourcefile} ${destinationfile2})
        else()
          set(destinationfile "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${targetFile}")
          set(sourcefile ${each_file2})
          Check(${sourcefile} ${destinationfile})
        endif()

    endforeach(each_file2)
endfunction()
```

It is executed `AddResources(project1)` in the CMakeLists.txt.

AddResources will copy all of resources and shaders to bin folder, but it copies only once(CMake configuration process), not every build-time.

Is there any way to execute CMake function every build-time with argument?

Comment: Do you **need** your `Check` function to be executed at *build* stage, or do you just **want** `destination` file to be updated whenever `source` file is changed? If you want only dependency checking (the second case), it can be done even on *configuration* stage. See, e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34799916/cmake-copy-file-from-source-directory-to-binary-directory). BTW, generating files in *source* directory (under `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`) normally is not good. Probably, you want to generate them in *build* directory (under `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html)

```
add_custom_command(TARGET target
               PRE_BUILD | PRE_LINK | POST_BUILD
               COMMAND command1 [ARGS] [args1...]
               [COMMAND command2 [ARGS] [args2...] ...]
               [WORKING_DIRECTORY dir]
               [COMMENT comment] [VERBATIM])
```

> This defines a new command that will be associated with building the specified target. When the command will happen is determined by which of the following is specified: 
>   PRE_BUILD - run before all other dependencies
>   PRE_LINK - run after other dependencies
>   POST_BUILD - run after the target has been built

Comment: Did I use it right? "COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/AddResources.cmake" project1" It causes error like that `MSB3073 The command "setlocal "...`

Comment: Okay. I tested that command in the Mac, there is no errors during compile process, but it doesn't change anything. That's not working

Comment: First of all, `AddResources.cmake` just defines a function without doing anything. More importantly I don't think you can use previously declared variables in scripts with `cmake -P` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13713505/400303)

Comment: I tried to execute COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/project1/Shaders/. ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/ in the add_custom_command, it doesn't copy files whenever I tried to build in the visual studio. I need to use another functionality in the CMake.

Comment: As you recommend, I also tried to put declared variables using -D option, but it is not working, so I did use copy command.

Comment: This solution is working for people (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6126754/400303). You should debug you script (eg `make VERBOSE=1`)