# How can I set CMAKE_BINARY_DIR in a CMake script invoked with -P?

Tags: cmake

From Stack Overflow posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792802/why-variables-are-not-accessed-inside-script-in-cmake) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712708/cmake-file-in-script-mode-inheriting-variables), I know that CMake scripts invoked with `-P` will not inherit any variables from the invoking CMakeLists.txt.

However, it appears that in addition to these not-inherited variables, certain variables will get contrived values:

> When run in cmake -P script mode, CMake sets the variables `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to the current working directory.
> <sub>https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.html</sub>

The above are illustrated in my CMakeLists and CMake scripts below:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── subdir
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── my_script.cmake
```

...and CMakeLists and CMake scripts as follows:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(learn-cmake-scipts VERSION 0.1.0)

add_subdirectory(subdir)
```

```
# subdir/CMakeLists.txt
set(FOO "bar")
message("In CMakeLists.txt, Foo=${FOO}")
message("In CMakeLists.txt, CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
message("In CMakeLists.txt, CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_custom_target(runscript
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script.cmake
  )
```

```
# subdir/my_script.cmake
message("In my_script.cmake, Foo=${FOO}")
message("In my_script.cmake, CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
message("In my_script.cmake, CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
```

```
$ rm -rf ./build/ && cmake -B build && cmake --build build --target runscript
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
In CMakeLists.txt, Foo=bar
In CMakeLists.txt, CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build
In CMakeLists.txt, CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build/subdir
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build
In my_script.cmake, Foo=
In my_script.cmake, CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build/subdir
In my_script.cmake, CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build/subdir
Built target runscript
$
```

Note that variable `FOO` is unset in the scope of my_script.cmake, as explained in the linked Stack Overflow posts.

I have read that to "inherit" variables from an invoking CMakeLists.txt, one should explicitly specify them as `-D` arguments in the `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P` invocation. **This seems to work for `FOO`, but not for `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` or `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`**. With this modified `add_custom_target()` invocation:

```
add_custom_target(runscript
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DFOO=${FOO} -DCMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/lorem/ipsum -DCMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=/dolor/sit -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script.cmake
  )
```

...only `FOO` is set in my_script.cmake's scope in line with its corresponding `-D` flag:

```
$ rm -rf ./build/ && cmake -B build && cmake --build build --target runscript
...
In CMakeLists.txt, Foo=bar
In CMakeLists.txt, CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build
In CMakeLists.txt, CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build/subdir
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build
In my_script.cmake, Foo=bar
In my_script.cmake, CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build/subdir
In my_script.cmake, CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=/home/user/dev/cmake-learn/scripts/build/subdir
Built target runscript
$
```

My question is: **is there a way to set `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, in the scope of the invoked CMake script, to its value in the scope of its invoking CMakeLists.txt?**

I understand that I can create my own variables, like `FOO`, `BAR`, or `BAZ` to carry any values I want from CMakeLists.txt to my_script.cmake, but certain variables like `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` have well-defined, well-understood values in CMake, therefore if I use that variable in my_script.cmake, its value and the intent of its use will be easily understood by future maintainers. If I used my own variables, no matter how well named they may be, it would require documentation, and would be more error-prone, etc. than "native" CMake variables.

---

I tried `add_custom_target(runscript COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DFOO=${FOO} -B ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_script.cmake)`, which made no difference from the above.